# How to check which background image div contains?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I have a div tag which can contain either 1 of the 3 images I have. Imagea, Imageb and ImageC as the background.

What I would like to do is write a if statement  to check if background image the div contains.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("divtag1"); 
    if(myDiv.style.backgroundImage == "url('images/plane.png')" ) {
        // Doing something
     }
```

This doesn't seem to work, any help is welcomed.

Comment: You are just missing one thing. You are looking if myDiv equals your provided string. Which can't be true because myDiv is an object. Just use myDiv.style.backgroundImage.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I edited my question. I not sure how I missed to write that in.

Comment: Are you using CSS to fill the Background-Image or are you using the 'SRC' attribute? Did you try to use '===' instead of '==' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use **JQuery**

```js
var background = $('.element').css('background-image')
if (background.indexOf("placehold.it/350x150") >= 0) {
  $('.element').css('border', '5px solid black');
}
```

```css
.element {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I am not too sure how I can adapt this in my code. I have never used jquery before and I the code I have written is full js.

Comment: You just need to include JQuery in your project before other js code https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/117/

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this code so you may need to fiddle with it a bit but to check the background image you would do something like:

```
if (myDiv.style.backgroundImage == "url('images/plane.png')")
{
    //DO SOMETHING.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property. I don't think you'll need [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) but I'll link to that too.

So something like:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("divtag1"); 
if(myDiv.style.backgroundImage === "url('images/plane.png')" ) {
    // Doing something
 }
```

Comment: What does myDiv.style.backgroundImage equal in the first place?  Run `console.log(myDiv.style.backgroundImage);` and let us know what it spits out.

Answer (score 1):

Here ye go. If you don't want to use regex, instead of `if(imgtest.test(backgroundimage))` you can also use `if(backgroundimage.indexOf('lion') > -1)`

```js
var lion = document.getElementById('lion');
var backgroundimage = window.getComputedStyle(lion).backgroundImage;
console.log(backgroundimage)

var imgtest = /lion/i; //regex to test for whatever string you need

if (imgtest.test(backgroundimage)) {
  console.log("Yes, this is a lion.")
}
```

```css
#lion {
  background: url(http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/articles/health_and_science/science/2015/07/150730_SCI_Cecil_lion.jpg.CROP.promo-xlarge2.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  width: 500px;
  height: 357px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lion"></div>
```